# Discord.py Embed text file

Tags: python, discord.py

I'd like to send on a Discord bot a message embed but text is from another file.
I did this way and it doesn't work:

```
@bot.command()
async def gdc(ctx):
    """Wins GDC"""
    message = '/home/plo/rkr/res_wins2'
    title = "GDC"
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.description = message
    embed.title = title
    embed.colour = 0xF1C40F
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

I have the embed message displaying the directory (/home/plo/rkr/res_wins2).

I modified it to read it before send it to Embed:

```
bot.command()
async def gdc(ctx):
    """Wins GDC"""
    index1 = 0
    file = open("/home/plo/rkr/res_wins2", "r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        index1 += 1
        if index1 == 4: break
    message = line
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.description = message
    embed.title = title
    embed.colour = 0xF1C40F
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

However, it seems only one result goes out... Here is my txt file:

```
Roi mouton: 9
tomate: 8
The_Portos: 8
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are the message in a `.txt` file? If this is true what you should do is read the file and pass it to a text string so you can match it to `message`. [Here](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html) you can find the documentation to Handling Files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Documentation [Here](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html).
It will help.
However using Java will be easier with like this:

```
channel.sendMessage("message").addFile(new File("path/to/file")).queue();
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.command()
async def gdc(ctx):
    """Wins GDC"""
    
    with open("/home/plo/rkr/res_wins2", "r") as f:
        scores = f.read().splitlines()
    
    final = '\n'.join(scores[0:3])
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Leader Board", description=final,color = 0xF1C40F)
    
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it in a for-loop:

```
@bot.command()
async def logs(ctx):
    embed: discord.Embed = discord.Embed(
        title="title", description="description",
        color=discord.Color.red()
    )
    file = open("file.txt", "r")
    for line in file.readlines():
        l = line.strip()
        loglist.append(l)
        embed.add_field(name="⠀", value=" `{0}`".format(l), inline=False)


    embed.set_author(name="name")
  
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```